# Reload iframe in another jquery tab

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jquery tabs, in which one tab has an iframe and the other has some settings for the content in the iframe.

When i update any content in second tab, how can i make it to reflect in the iframe of first tab.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `location.reload` on the iframe?

Comment: i have used the code, $('#myiframe').attr('src', sourcepath);